# How to bind function after appendTo

Tags: jquery, bind, appendto

I'm trying to do something right after an ajax call (data) has finished loading the data in my div:

```
$(data).find('a').appendTo('#DIV').bind(function(e){

$(this).prop('href', function(_, href){
    url = href.split('/');          
    return href.replace(url[2], 'someUrl');
})   

});
```

So after the appendTo Im doing the href split and replace. It doesnt work, meaning the data gets loaded but the binded function split/replace doesnt catch up. What else can I try?

Comment: the function split and replace...

Comment: `.bind()` is for events: `.bind('click', function(e) {...`. Just to make sure that we're on the same page here, why did you choose to bind that function instead of just chaining it?

Comment: I derived it from some other code, I was just putting stuff together out of frustration I guess:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to bind().. bind() is for events.. just use the prop() straight away..

try this

```
 $(data).find('a')
        .appendTo('#DIV')
        .prop('href', function(_, href){ 
                  url = href.split('/');
                  return href.replace(url[2], 'someUrl');
                  });
```